# Does a topological space always admit a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, group-actions, fixed-points

Recently I have been reading a lot about $\mathbb{Z}_2$-actions on topological spaces. Mainly I was focused on surfaces such as the sphere, torus and Klein bottle and here the existence of a nontrivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action is rather simple. But I was wondering if a general topological space always admits a nontrivial continuous $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action? If not, then more specific, does a manifold always admit a nontrivial continuous $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action?

For a manifold $M$ I was thinking about the fact that we can embed $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N >0$ and then $M$ can inherit a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action from $\mathbb{R}^N$ but then when one looks at the spiral in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we see that this spiral does not inherit for example the antipodality of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Extra: I was also wondering that if there are spaces that do admit a nontrivial continuous $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action, do these space then also admit a **free** $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action? By free I mean that the action is fixed point free.

If anyone knows some basic examples that do not admit a continuous (free) $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action. Please do share. I seem to be unable to find one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Even if you embed your manifold in $R^n$ it may not inherit a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action as it needs to be mapped to itself by $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I guess that you mean a *nontrivial* $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action? Because you can always let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ act trivially, $g \cdot x = x$. As for a space that does not admit a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action, consider a singleton.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Indeed, I mean a nontrivial action ;) I edited it in my question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Alright, that is a rather simple example. One I totally missed. Thank you!

Comment: Also you mean "continuous" nontrivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action? Because without that assumption every set with at least 2 elements admits a nontrivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action.

Comment: @freakish Yes, indeed. I silently assumed this since I'm mainly working continuous maps between manifolds. My bad for not mentioning it. Thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at all, but it's a fun relevant fact : the only free actions even-dimensional spheres can have are $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$-actions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $X=[0,1)$. By connectedness arguments it follows that $0$ is fixed by every homeomorphism and as a consequence every $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on $X$ is trivial (to verify this, show that every subset of the form $[0,\varepsilon]$ gets fixed).

If we consider manifolds then I can't give you examples that do not admit a non-trivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action (which do not consist of only one point). However, if we consider free actions then the quotient is a manifold and we obtain a covering. It is a consequence of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem that the only free actions on $S^{2n}$ are trivial or given by $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But if $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ had a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action, then the quotient would have a fundamental group of order $4$ with universal covering $S^{2n}$, which is not possible.

Comment: In https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01450714, the authors show that if $\Sigma$ is an exotic sphere, then $T^n \# \Sigma$ does not admit any smooth action by any compact Lie group (including finite groups).  Of course, being homeomorphic to $T^n$, such examples admit many continuous actions by any subgroup of $T^n$.

Answer (score 4):

$X=\mathbb R$ easily admits a nontrivial $\mathbb Z_2$-action, but it cannot be free -- we can always find a fixed point with the intermediate value theorem.