# What is an involutorial homeomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, semigroups, topological-semigroups

Having searched the term "**involutorial**" here, on Google, and in the references of the source paper [where I first have met this term](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183519418) (in fact the only time), I am wondering whether could anyone give a definition of an **involutorial homeomorphism**. The location of this term in the paper is Theorem 2.4 on page 98.

Could it be that the source paper is dated 1955?

Comment: As the author writes $\theta(\theta(x))=x$, I guess he means that it is an involutive homeomorphism

Comment: Some sources such as [this recent quedtion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215553/does-a-topological-space-always-admit) speak of $\mathbb Z_2$-actions (on a topological space)  instead, which are effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *involutorial homeomorphism* is a homeomorphism that is also an involution. An *involution* is a function $f$ that satisfies $f^2=\operatorname{id}$, i.e. an function that is its own inverse. See also the [Wikipedia page on involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)), which states at the outset that an *involutory function* is the same as an *involution*.

Comment: I wonder whether *involutorial* is used often, as opposed to *involutory* or *involutive*.  That Wallace paper was from 1955, so maybe it was more common then.

Comment: @GEdgar I have never seen *involutorial*, though its meaning is clear enough to me. I can imagine this not to be as clear to a non-native English speaker. Then again, I have rarely seen *involutory*, it's pretty much always *involutive* in my (limited) experience.